# Villager's don't move on to the next livestock after gathering food

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

I built a livestock pen in AOE3 in the hopes of not having to chase around the wild animals when hunting since the sheep and cattle just sit there and let you kill them.

Unfortunately my settlers do not move on to another sheep/cow when they finish with one, as a result I have to constantly micromanage the settlers and livestock to keep my food supply consistent.

I am not sure if I am missing something or if they're supposed to be less manageable as part of the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Villagers do move on the next animal at the livestock pen, but I think your problem is that they have to be fully fattened. It's better economically if you let them fatten usually, so try making more sheep or waiting a bit before you kill them. You'll be getting more food, and your villagers will move on to the next sheep automatically as well.